# Jackson Hibernate relationship by id

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson, quarkus, quarkus-panache

*Note: I unfortunately don't really have an idea of what library my problem concerns, if you need any further information please just write a comment!*

I have two hibernate panache entity classes declared like this:

```java
@Entity
public class FirstObj extends PanacheEntity {
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "secondobj_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  public SecondObj secondObj;
  public String name;
}

@Entity
public class SecondObj extends PanacheEntity {
  public String name;
  public int weight;
}
```

And I want to be able to deserialize this object with this json (deserialized by jackson, assuming there's an entry in the `SecondObj` table with the id 1):

```json
{
  "name": "hello",
  "secondObj": 1
}
```

Is this possible? I don't want it to automatically create a new `SecondObj` entity on requests.

Comment: So if you receive "secondObj": 1, you want to deserialize it to the appropriate secondObj?

Comment: Exactly, it should put in a reference to the existing entity

Comment: I'd recommend a DTO/VO approach instead, where you have your `FirstObj` and an accompanying `FirstObjDTO` class where `secondObj` is represented as `secondObjId`. If you'd like I can elaborate in an answer, since it isn't what you asked for in your question.

Comment: Seems interesting, please go ahead and elaborate a bit more! I've looked into what DTO's are and it seems like it could be useful for my usecase, if I understood it correctly you wrap your classes with only the things you need and make a deserialzation strategy or something that translates these wrapper objects -> the actual ones, and then I can use these ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend achieving this using the [DTO pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dto-pattern). When applied to your example, in addition to

```java
@Entity
public class FirstObj extends PanacheEntity {
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "secondobj_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  public SecondObj secondObj;
  public String name;
}
```

You will have another class -

```java
public class FirstObjDTO extends PanacheDTO {
  public String name;
  public long secondObjId;
}
```

From that point you can use a mapping library or a mapping function to map `FirstObj.secondObj.id` to `FirstObjDTO.secondObjId` prior to serialization.

### Example mapping function:

```java
FirstObjDTO toFirstObjDto(FirstObj from) {
  FirstObjDTO dto = new FirstObjDTO();
  dto.setName(from.getName());
  if (from.getSecondObj() != null) {
    dto.setSecondObjId(from.getSecondObj().getId());
  }
  return dto;
}
```

You can also use a mapping library, one such library is [ShapeShift](https://github.com/krud-dev/shapeshift). (*Disclaimer: I am a contributor to ShapeShift*)

### Mapping example

```java
@Entity
public class FirstObj extends PanacheEntity {
  @MappedField(target = FirstObjDTO.class, mapFrom = "id", mapTo = "secondObjId")
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "secondobj_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  public SecondObj secondObj;

  @MappedField(target = FirstObjDTO.class)
  public String name;
}
```

Then wherever you intend to perform this mapping:

```java
ShapeShift shapeShift = ShapeShift();
FirstObjDTO firstObjDTO = shapeShift.map(firstObj, FirstObjDTO.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How do I use this for deserialization (JSON -> Entity / DTO -> non-dto)?

Comment: From your endpoint accept the DTO instead of the entity, then apply the solution above in the reverse direction (DTO -> entity). If you'd like to share a bit more of your code (Specifically the web layer) I can give you more accurate pointers. Serialization to/from JSON at this point should be done against the DTO class.

Answer (score 0):

Please try some annotation like this link : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations

Int the case it is not enough for your answer please validate your input before use it